# Convert MethodBody to Expression Tree

Tags: .net-4.0, linq-expressions

Is there a way to convert a MethodBody (or other Reflection technique) into a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression tree?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use the `MethodBody`?

Comment: Is there something else? I mentioned it because it's where you get the IL byte array.

Comment: Yes, there is something else. You would also need `MethodBase`, since this is where you access the method signature (parameters' and return value's type); you would need that in order to build a [`LambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You're basically asking for a somewhat simpler version of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: Well, it was Reflector that made me wonder if it was possible.

Comment: @Chris: If you rewrite Reflector, yes.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible, see DelegateDecompiler:

https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

NOTE: I am *not* affiliated with this project

*Edit*

Here is the basic approach that the project takes:

1. Get MethodInfo for the method you want to convert
2. Use methodInfo.GetMethodBody to get a MethodBody object. This contains, 
   among other things, the MSIL and info on arguments and locals
3. Go through the instructions, examine the opcodes, and build the appropriate Expressions
4. Tie it all together and return an optimized Expression

Here is a code snippet from the project that decompiles a method body:

```
 public class MethodBodyDecompiler
    {
        readonly IList<Address> args;
        readonly VariableInfo[] locals;
        readonly MethodInfo method;

        public MethodBodyDecompiler(MethodInfo method)
        {
            this.method = method;
            var parameters = method.GetParameters();
            if (method.IsStatic)
                args = parameters
                    .Select(p => (Address) Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name))
                    .ToList();
            else
                args = new[] {(Address) Expression.Parameter(method.DeclaringType, "this")}
                    .Union(parameters.Select(p => (Address) Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name)))
                    .ToList();

            var body = method.GetMethodBody();
            var addresses = new VariableInfo[body.LocalVariables.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.Length; i++)
            {
                addresses[i] = new VariableInfo(body.LocalVariables[i].LocalType);
            }
            locals = addresses.ToArray();
        }

        public LambdaExpression Decompile()
        {
            var instructions = method.GetInstructions();
            var ex = Processor.Process(locals, args, instructions.First(), method.ReturnType);
            return Expression.Lambda(new OptimizeExpressionVisitor().Visit(ex), args.Select(x => (ParameterExpression) x.Expression));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. In this case, I am not sure what to include since the project I linked as a whole is required to answer. Maybe summarize the approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible... but it hasn't been done yet, as far as I know.

> <sub>*If anyone* does *know of a library that de-compiles methods to expression trees, please let me know, or edit the above statement.*</sub>

The most difficult part of what you would have to do is write a [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) de-compiler. That is, you would need to translate the fairly low-level CIL instructions (which conceptually target a stack machine) into much higher-level expressions.

Tools such as Redgate's [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) or Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/justdecompile.aspx) do just that, but instead of building expression trees, they display source code; you could say they go one step further, since expression trees are basically still language-agnostic.

Some notable cases where this would get especially tricky:

- You would have to deal with cases of CIL instructions for which no pre-defined `Expression` tree node exists; let's say, `tail.call`, or `cpblk` (I'm guessing a little here). That is, you'd have to create custom expression tree node types; having them compiled back into an executable method when you `.Compile()` the expression tree might be an issue, because the expression tree compiler tries to break down custom nodes into standard nodes. If that is not possible, then you cannot compile the expression tree any more, you could only inspect it.
- Would you try to recognise certain high-level constructs, such as a C# `using` block, and try to build a (custom) expression tree node for it? Remember that C# `using` breaks down to the equivalent of `try…finally { someObj.Dispose(); }` during compilation, so that is what you might see instead of `using` if you reflected over the [method body's CIL instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray.aspx) and [exception handling clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.exceptionhandlingclauses.aspx).

  Thus, in general, expect that you need to be able to "recognise" certain code patterns and summarise them into a higher-level concept.